# Notation for changing a component of a vector

Tags: notation, vectors

Is there a notation for changing a component of a vector in a specific index to a different number? Or is such an operation not used in maths? E.g. in programming languages you can do something like `vector = [1, 2, 3]; vector[0] = 4`.

If there is no way of showing changing a component by changing the vector itself, is there a notation for showing a new vector with the same components as the other vector apart from the component that is being changed? So e.g. in the example above the new vector would be `[4, 2, 3]`.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific notation, but you want to look at projections. In your example you project vector v into the x=4 plane.

Comment: More generally, in math we usually don't *change* things about objects as in most programming languages. We typically describe new objects as in some [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) languages.

Answer (score 0):

This is odd, but you may simply define a vector $\mathbf{x} = [x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}]^T$ where $x_i$ denotes the $i$th element of $\mathbf{x}$. For example, you may then modify individual element as either

$$x_i = \alpha$$
or
$$x_i \leftarrow \alpha$$

where $\alpha$ is a number.